# What is the use of gulp-sourcemaps?

Tags: npm, gulp, package, package.json

I'm learning angular2 and I have seen the gulp-sourcemaps plugin used in the angular2-quickstart project. My question is general, why we use the gulp-sourcemaps? In what circumstances I should use this plugin?

Answer (score 9):

It automatically creates source maps from your code. A source map is used to tell you which file and line in your original code a part of minified code comes from. So sourcemaps can be very helpful when debugging minified Angular apps in the browser.